# Auto trailing return type?

Tags: c++

I was surprised to see this works in C++14:

```
auto b() -> auto
{}
```

In C++11 I get the error `error: invalid use of 'auto'`.

How does this code work?

Answer (score 2):

The capsule summary: in C++14 the return type of a lambda (or a function, in most instances) can be given as `auto`, and then compiler figures out what the actual return type is based on the `return` statement from the lamba/function.

In this case, nothing is returned, so the return type is `void`.

Comment: Is a function declared this way identical to `auto function()` without the trailing return type?

Comment: @Kundor, Yes, it is.